# Reusing ViewModels and Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm quite new to ASP MVC so when I first created a page I made a ViewModel that has flattened properties related to Address and Contact information. These properties are very common and I can see them being reused. So let's say I have the view model below:

```
public class InformationViewModel {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public Uri WebSiteURL { get; set; }
    public Uri FacebookURL { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AttentionLine { get; set; }
    public string CareOf { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Countries { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> States { get; set; }
    public string StateCode { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    //Some other properties specific to the view here
}
```

The first two blocks of properties are reusable across multiple view models. Now I'm working on a new page that requires these same properties.

1) Would I separate them out into their own View Model (or Model?) files (e.g. AddressViewModel/ContactViewModel)?

1a) If I do separate them out and reuse them by including them as a property in `InformationViewModel` would that be with the line: `public AddressViewModel addressViewModel {get; set;}`?

2) How would I remove or apply data annotations in an included view model (e.g. `public AddressViewModel addressViewModel {get; set;}`? For example, if I want Name to be required on some Views but not for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View models are specific to views. So it is a good idea to create view specific flat view models. But if you have some common attributes in more than one view models, you may inherit from a base view model as needed.

```
public class CreateUser
{
  [Required]
  public string Name {set;get;}
  [Required]
  public string Email {set;get;}

  public virtual string City { set; get; }
}
public class CreateUserWithAddress : CreateUser
{
  [Required]
  public string AddressLine1 {set;get;}
  public string AddressLine12 {set;get;}

  [Required]
  public override string City { set; get; }  // make city required
}
```

When inhering from a base view model, you should be able to override a property of base class and add a data annotation to that in your child class (*Like we did with `City` property*). But you cannot remove the data annotation defined in the base class inside your derived class.

Comment: If you use an interface instead your VM can implement many "base" types e.g. `CreateUserWithAddress : ICreateUser, ICreateAddress`.